# Sempre iniciar MongoDB

Tags: windows, mongodb

Sempre quando vou usar MongoDB em um ambiente de desenvolvimento local, tenho que abrir o terminal e digitar:

```
mongod
```

Para que possa usar os serviços do MongoDB.

Tendo em vista que meu sistema operacional é Windows10 (64 bits), como faço para sempre iniciar este processo automaticamente, sem ter que manter um terminal aberto só para rodar o `mongod`?

Nesse contexto, se eu quiser desativar essa inicialização automática, como seria o procedimento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode definir o mongoDB como serviço, para ser inicializado junto com o Windows.

```
mongod --dbpath "{{seu_diretorio_do_mongo}}" --logpath "{{seu_diretorio_do_mongo}}\logs.txt" --install --serviceName "MongoDB"
```

Depois, na tela de serviços do windows, você pode definir o serviço para inicialização automatica.

[Pergunta em ingles para referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969325/how-to-install-mongodb-as-service-on-windows-8-1)

[Link da documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#connect-to-mongodb)